# Html.BeginCollectionItem("Gifts")) { } Does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can any one please help me .

```
@model LioM.Models.Gift
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Gifts"))
{

}
```

this is my MVC5 partial view. It shows an error does not contain a definition for `BeginCollectionItem`

Comment: Have you downloaded and correctly installed the Nuget package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install [BeginCollectionItem HtmlHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) from nuget:

`PM> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem`

And make sure it's `Namespace` is in your view:

```
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem
```

Comment: Thanks Brother Its Working fine

Answer (score 1):

Can also add

```
<add namespace="HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem" />
```

to the namespaces in the web.config of the Views folder.  Mine was in an "Areas" folder so I needed to add it there.